# How to do a full uninstall (reinstall) of fabric8 on macOS?

Tags: macos, fabric8

I was experimenting a bit with fabric8 and trying it out on my local macOS machine. I ran into some issues with my local installations of brew, docker and virtualbox. As some of the dependencies for fabric8 are installed using brew in such an environment, I wanted to do a clean reinstall of plenty of components/dependencies on my local machine.

But I cannot find any uninstall instructions for fabric8. I can manually uninstall the brew formulas docker-machine and the xhyve driver, I can see the .fabric8 folder in my home directory and just delet that, but what am I supposed to do to properly uninstall fabric8 and all of it's dependencies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd start by deleting the VM:

```
  minikube delete
```

Did you use gofabric8 to install everything?  gofabric8 uses minikube by default or minishift if the flag was specified when running `gofabric8 start`, if you want to completely remove these then you can

```
rm -rf ~/.minikube
```

or

```
rm -rf ~/.minishift
```

and as you mentioned

```
rm -rf ~/.fabric8
```

FWIW once you have minikube running you can remove the fabric8 elements that are deployed on it by running `gofabric8 cleanup`

Comment: I was under the impression that gofabric8 installs some dependencies locally to run, and not all of them reside inside a container, the k8s cluster, or the ~/.gofabric8 folder (on OSX at least). After removing the brew formulas above and those two folders I hope all is removed for now and I can have a fresh start if needed.